# Handle app uninstallation via android apps menu in android 4+ versions

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-4.2-jelly-bean

From ice-cream sandwich & above versions, application can be uninstalled without going to settings but in apps menu & simply selecting uninstall. But before android 4.0, if user open settings we can restrict accessing it by using password prompt, etc with activityManager.runningTasks().
Can a similar scenario be applied to this new uninstallation proceedure.
I tried to capture activity name, label, processs name when user click on uninstall on menu, but no luck yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Fortunately, the tricks you are describing are being blocked, to prevent malware authors from harming users. If you wish for your app to not be uninstalled, please arrange to have it shipped pre-installed on a device or custom ROM.

Comment: No. still even for jelly been we can block settings. Only issue is on that apps menu uninstallation feature.

Comment: You assume that Jelly Bean is the final Android release, and that your situation will never change.

Comment: as long as when open the settings, if it gives different app name, we can block users from accessing it & I do not think it is a security breach as users can see app capabilities before it is being installed.

Comment: There is no "app capability" for "prevent you from uninstalling the app" or "prevent you from using your device as you see fit".

Comment: What I meant by app capabilities was getting task  info. If one is accessing device task info, this kind of  logic can be implemented  in any device regardless of the Rom  os type

Comment: I also find the  solution for this. As a clue, just analyse the log cat via  your app  & it will log a perfect  string  before uninstallation both in ics & jelly bean

Comment: Fortunately, you cannot read LogCat on Jelly Bean, except for messages that you log yourself, as you can no longer hold the `READ_LOGS` permission (unless you are part of the firmware).

Comment: yes that's true. but I guess still We can read full system log via adb